vue TransitionGroup scaleY() works, but scale() and scaleX() don't
I have a Vue 3.4.27 and with a  as an unordered list.  If I set the css up to use scaleY(0) it works.  If I use scale(0) or scaleX(0) vue is somehow adding a translateX() in so that the it both scales the text and slides it in from the right.
Maybe I'm not understanding scaleX() properly, but using scaleY(), the element is placed in its final location in the list and then gradually grows taller.  I would expect scaleX to be placed in its final location and gradually scale out to fill its complete location.  Maybe that's just not right?
I set up a playground, but when I tested it in firefox it gave me an error.  Chrome was ok though.
If the playground is broken, I've got the group set up like this:
    <TransitionGroup
      name="grow-y"
      tag="ul"
      class="container"
      appear
    >
      <li v-for="(name, index) in names" :key="index">
        {{name}}
        <button @click="names.splice(index, 1);" >-</button>
      </li>
    </TransitionGroup>

<hr>
    <div>Using scaleX()</div>
    <transition-group
      name="grow-x"
      tag="ul"
      class="container"
      appear
    >
      <li v-for="(name, index) in names" :key="index">
        {{name}}
        <button @click="names.splice(index, 1);" >-</button>
      </li>
    </transition-group>

And the css:
  .grow-x-enter,
  .grow-x-leave-to,
  .grow-x-enter-from {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  }

  .grow-y-enter,
  .grow-y-leave-to,
  .grow-y-enter-from {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  /**
    all transitions will share the animation types
   */
  .grow-x-enter-active,
  .grow-x-leave-active,
  .grow-x-move,
  .grow-y-enter-active,
  .grow-y-leave-active,
  .grow-y-move {
    transition: all 5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  }

Any ideas?

What works and what doesn't in your example? Specify the problem!

When using scale() or scaleX() in the transition, vue is somehow adding a translateX() in so that the it both scales the text and slides it in from the right.

Stupid edit rule.  scaleY() transitions grow along the Y axis and do it in place.  Scale() and scaleX() animations slide in from the right, both scale() and translateX() even though there's no translate in my css.  That's a long explanation, but the playground should work and show it better than I can describe.
